# How do I format date in TSql when I use json_value

Tags: sql-server, json, datetime, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Server 2016 and I am storing json. When I extract it, the datetime format does not show clean. How do I format the datetime format?

```
select 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.entrytime') AS entrytime 
from 
    dbo.Trades
```

Values shown:

```
2016-05-23T05:21:30.3068919-04:00
2016-05-24T10:49:16.337257-04:00
2016-05-24T11:05:30.8941267-04:00
2016-05-24T11:37:35.9555731-04:00
```

How do I format those dates in the `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format?

Comment: Save your date/time formatting for your application/presentation layer, don't do it in the query. The format you're getting is "clean" - it's the ISO 8601 standard.

Comment: I am trying to fix it in my presentation layer. I am running query to see the data and want to see it formatted properly so I can analyse it. So how do I format the date to see it properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `FORMAT`:

```
select FORMAT(CAST(JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.entrytime') as datetimeoffset), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') AS entrytime from dbo.Trades
```

Comment: I get a Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Agrr... forgot about the timezone. Case it to `datetimeoffset` instead of `datetime`.

Comment: since this makes it a datetime object, I prefer this solution better than the other one. however for some weird reason, sql server seems to take few seconds longer to process this even though I only have 25 json records

Comment: Haven't worked with JSON in SQL Server I can't be of help here. I suspect it's the JSON parsing part that takes a long time. If it's too long, extract the string value to a staging table, then apply `FORMAT` on that.

Answer (score 0):

You want to format the following timestamp to look like the one following it:

```
2016-05-24T11:37:35.9555731-04:00
2016-05-24 11:37:35
```

The following query replaces the `T` with a space, and also substrings off everything which comes after (and including) the period.

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.entrytime'), 1,
                         CHARINDEX('.', JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.entrytime')) - 1),
               'T', ' ') AS entrytime
FROM dbo.Trades
```

Comment: I get no space between date and time. how can I correct it?
2016-05-2305:21:30

Comment: Sorry I used empty string instead of space.  Try again, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(33), GetDate(), 126)

> SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(33), GetDate(), 126),19)+'Z'

could be worth a look