# json sql with list items

Tags: sql-server, json

I have json stored in sql2016. when I run a query parts of the json returns value and other parts don't return value.
here is a json stored in table dbo.Trades
The datatype is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Trades](
[_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[trade] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
```

My json is formatted as below and stored in trade column

```
{
  "direction": "Short",
  "Powerbars": 2,
  "PowerbarsTime": [
    "2016-11-10T20:25:32.481424-05:00",
    "2016-11-10T20:44:01.8993031-05:00"
  ]
}
```

Since Powerbarstime is a list in the json, I have to provide the index to print it. however I don't know how many  entries will eb there in the list. Is there a way to merge the list which is part of the json and return a comma delimited column?

I have to do this to print

```
SELECT        _id, 
JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.Powerbars') AS powerbars,
JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.PowerbarsTime[0]') AS PowerbarsTime1,
JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.PowerbarsTime[1]') AS PowerbarsTime2
FROM            dbo.Trades
order by _id desc
```

I get the 2 items on the list that I hardcode into the sql.

[image: results]

How can I merge all the list items under `JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.PowerbarsTime')` so I can see it all as 1 comma delimited column.

Comment: Does the answer in your question here help any http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450492/how-do-i-format-date-in-tsql-when-i-use-json-value?  Perhaps it's the value of the datetime value that is inserted into the PowerbarsTime that needs formatted differently to be able to be inserted into that column based on the data type, etc.? In other words, try it with `FORMAT(CAST(JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.PowerbarsTime') as datetimeoffset), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') AS entrytime from dbo.Trades` instead and see what results you get. Otherwise, you might tell how the data type is set for that table column.

Comment: I redefined the prob as the json has a list and I need to figure out a way to convert the list into a comma delimited column

Comment: If applicable you might look into [OpenJSON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921885.aspx) to see if you can build a query to pull out the list within the JSON data as you need. You might also research [FOR JSON PATH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921882.aspx) as this may be the best approach for something similar I've done with OPEN XML PATH with SQL Server. Just trying to give you some good starting points since I cannot test at the moment with your sample data.